# d3.js stacked bar chart - modify stack order logic

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to create a stacked bar chart whereby the order of the rects is determined by data values (i.e. largest to smallest, tallest to shortest, richest to poorest, ect). To the best of my knowledge, after stacking data, the *initial* order seems to be preserved. This can be seen in my snippet, hardcoded data lets us see what's happening before and after `d3.stack()`. Note that the third rect `fmc3` goes from being the third largest in `t1` to the largest of all rects in `t3` despite its position in the stack remaining the same:

```js
var margins = {top:100, bottom:300, left:100, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', totalWidth)
.attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");


  var data = [
{period:'t1', fmc1:2, fmc2:5, fmc3:6, fmc4:9, fmc5:10},
{period:'t2', fmc1:3, fmc2:4, fmc3:9, fmc4:8, fmc5:11},
{period:'t3', fmc1:3, fmc2:5, fmc3:15, fmc4:12, fmc5:10},
  ];

  var groups = d3.map(data, function(d){return(d.period)}).keys();

var subgroups = Object.keys(data[0]).slice(1);

  var stackedData = d3.stack()
   .keys(subgroups)
   (data);

//console.log(stackedData);

  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,80])
  .range([height,0]);

  var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(['t1','t2','t3'])
  .range([0,width])
  .padding([.5]);

  var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(subgroups)
  .range(["#003366","#366092","#4f81b9","#95b3d7","#b8cce4","#e7eef8","#a6a6a6","#d9d9d9","#ffffcc","#f6d18b","#e4a733","#b29866","#a6a6a6","#d9d9d9","#e7eef8","#b8cce4","#95b3d7","#4f81b9","#366092","#003366"].reverse());

  graphGroup.append("g")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(stackedData)
  .enter().append("g")
.attr("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.key); })
.selectAll("rect")
.data(function(d) { return d; })
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.data.period); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d[1]); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return yScale(d[0]) - yScale(d[1]); })
  .attr("width",xScale.bandwidth());
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

I suspect preserving the initial order may be somewhat necessary to calculate adjacent rects in the stack. However, on the other hand, ordering data before visualizing it is a very common, even preferred practice in the field of visualization and I would be surprised if no one has found a solution to this issue yet.

### Question

Given there are no built-in features to specify the ordering of the rects in a stack, how should I approach the sort logic to achieve largest to smallest ordering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there **is** a built-in feature to specify the order, which is [`stack.order()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#stack_order). However, it specifies the order computing the *entire series*, not every single value the stack (which I believe is what you want... in that case, you'll have to create your own function).

So, for instance, using `stack.order(d3.stackOrderDescending)`:

```js
var margins = {
  top: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  left: 0,
  right: 0
};

var height = 300;
var width = 500;

var totalWidth = width + margins.left + margins.right;
var totalHeight = height + margins.top + margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', totalWidth)
  .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', "translate(" + margins.left + "," + margins.top + ")");


var data = [{
    period: 't1',
    fmc1: 2,
    fmc2: 5,
    fmc3: 6,
    fmc4: 9,
    fmc5: 10
  },
  {
    period: 't2',
    fmc1: 3,
    fmc2: 4,
    fmc3: 9,
    fmc4: 8,
    fmc5: 11
  },
  {
    period: 't3',
    fmc1: 3,
    fmc2: 5,
    fmc3: 15,
    fmc4: 12,
    fmc5: 10
  },
];

var groups = d3.map(data, function(d) {
  return (d.period)
}).keys();

var subgroups = Object.keys(data[0]).slice(1);

var stackedData = d3.stack()
  .keys(subgroups)
  .order(d3.stackOrderDescending)
  (data);

//console.log(stackedData);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 60])
  .range([height, 0]);

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(['t1', 't2', 't3'])
  .range([0, width])
  .padding([.5]);

var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(subgroups)
  .range(["#003366", "#366092", "#4f81b9", "#95b3d7", "#b8cce4", "#e7eef8", "#a6a6a6", "#d9d9d9", "#ffffcc", "#f6d18b", "#e4a733", "#b29866", "#a6a6a6", "#d9d9d9", "#e7eef8", "#b8cce4", "#95b3d7", "#4f81b9", "#366092", "#003366"].reverse());

graphGroup.append("g")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(stackedData)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return colorScale(d.key);
  })
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return xScale(d.data.period);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return yScale(d[0]) - yScale(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth());
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. It also confirms my suspicion that we don't have built-in sorting at the value-level. I may also need to understand what's going on under the hood of such a custom function, if that's what we need.